# MFT rule which filters packet by ip length

Tags: linux-kernel, netfilter, nft, nftables

I want to create a rule which can accept only these packets which have ip length greater than 2000

so I have my table (my_table) and chain(my_chain)
and I am trying something like this:

```
sudo nft add rule inet my_table my_chain ip length > 2000 counter accept
```

but I've got the error:

> `-bash: 2000: No such file or directory

I believe that there is a problem with '<'. How can I rewrite this rule without using comparison operators? Cause this is working:

```
sudo nft add rule inet my_table my_chain ip length != 2000 counter accept
```

but it has different meaning

Answer (score 0):

ok so ip length != 1-2000 is working

Answer (score 0):

The shell interprets `>` as a redirect, so it needs to be escaped with a backslash.

```
sudo nft add rule inet my_table my_chain ip length \> 2000 counter accept
```